# 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' is not a valid value for property 'SelectedIndex'

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selectedindex, markup-extensions

Can someone please shed some light on this error?

At first I thought SelectedIndex is probably just not a DependencyProperty and cannot be bound, but I was wrong.

If I use a normal binding instead of the markup extension `src:ValidatedBinding`, or if I keep the markup extension but bind `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedIndex`, then it works.

Here is a small app to demonstrate the problem.

The main window:

```
<Window       x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
                Title="MainWindow" 
               Height="350" 
                Width="525"
                     >
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{src:ValidatedBinding SelectedIndex}"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
        <ComboBoxItem>Not Specified</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>First</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Second</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

The code behind the main window:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main window.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new Item { Description = "Item 1", SelectedIndex = 0 };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An object with a string and an int property.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class Item
    {
        int _selectedIndex;
        string _description;

        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; }
        }

        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedIndex; }
            set { _selectedIndex = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the markup extension:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a normal Binding but defaults NotifyOnValidationError and 
    /// ValidatesOnExceptions to True, Mode to TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger
    /// to LostFocus.
    /// </summary>
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Binding))]
    public sealed class ValidatedBinding : MarkupExtension
    {
        public ValidatedBinding(string path)
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;

            Path = path;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var Target = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));

            /* on combo boxes, use an immediate update and validation */
            DependencyProperty DP = Target.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
            if (DP != null && DP.OwnerType == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector)
                && UpdateSourceTrigger == UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus) {
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            }

            return new Binding(Path) {
                Converter = this.Converter,
                ConverterParameter = this.ConverterParameter,
                ElementName = this.ElementName,
                FallbackValue = this.FallbackValue,
                Mode = this.Mode,
                NotifyOnValidationError = true,
                StringFormat = this.StringFormat,
                ValidatesOnExceptions = true,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = this.UpdateSourceTrigger
            };
        }

        public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }

        public object ConverterParameter { get; set; }

        public string ElementName { get; set; }

        public object FallbackValue { get; set; }

        public BindingMode Mode { get; set; }

        [ConstructorArgument("path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string StringFormat { get; set; }

        public UpdateSourceTrigger UpdateSourceTrigger { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The exception when I run this application:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
>   HResult=-2146233087   Message=**'Set property
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectedIndex' threw an
>   exception.**' Line number '9' and line position '19'.
>   Source=PresentationFramework   LineNumber=9   LinePosition=19
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject,
>   XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>          at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
>          at WpfApplication2.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml:line 1
>          at WpfApplication2.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 12
>   InnerException: System.ArgumentException
>          HResult=-2147024809
>          Message=**'System.Windows.Data.Binding' is not a valid value for property 'SelectedIndex'**.
>          Source=WindowsBase
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
>               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object
>   value)
>               at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance,
>   Object value)
>               at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member,
>   Object obj, Object value)
>               at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst,
>   XamlMember property, Object value)
>          InnerException:

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is an `int`. You can't put a `System.Windows.Data.Binding` inside an `int` property. Your `MarkupExtension` is wrong. You're returning the `Binding` itself instead of evaluating it and returning the `Binding Source`.

Comment: @HighCore - But a normal `{Binding xxx}` is not an `int` either. I don't understand. If I were to use `{Binding SelectedIndex}` instead of `{src:ValidatedBinding SelectedIndex}` then it would work, and essentially both return a binding. Where am I missing the boat?

Comment: The `Binding` markup extension does not return a `Binding` instance, it creates the binding and returns the value in the other end (the Source)

Comment: @HighCore - Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense, except the markup extension works on `SelectedItem`. Does `SelectedItem` disregard the binding and assign the value instead?

Comment: `SelectedItem` is of type `object`, that's why you're not getting an exception, but that doesn't mean it's working. It's not, you're just assigning an instance of the `Binding` class to the `SelectedItem` property.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a proxy binding that works if anyone is interested.

Thank you @HighCore for pointing me in the right direction.

I use this binding proxy to set non-standard default values on the binding so I don't have to set them everywhere. This makes my xaml more compact, and allows me to have a central place where I 'style' my bindings.

These are the defaults:

- NotifyOnValidationError = True,
- ValidatesOnExceptions = True,
- Mode = TwoWay,
- UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus for 'Text' properties, otherwise PropertyChanged.

The `UpdateSourceTrigger` will change to `PropertyChanged` if the target property is not a `Text` property. (e.g. Combos or CheckBoxes)

If I don't need validation, I use the normal binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
```

If I need a normal two way binding, I know I might need validation so I use this binding proxy:

```
<TextBox Text="{i:ValidatedBinding FirstName}" />
```

That means I don't have to write out:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName
    , Mode=TwoWay
    , UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus
    , NotifyOnValidationError=True
    , ValidatesOnExceptions=True" />
```

It works on both `SelectedItem` (reference types) and `SelectedIndex` (value types).

It will monitor the DataContext and maintain the binding.

If you find holes in the code, fix bugs or have any suggestions, please let me know.

```
using ITIS.Reflection /* you can replace this with System.Reflection */;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace ITIS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Binding with the following defaults:
    /// <para>- NotifyOnValidationError = True, </para>
    /// <para>- ValidatesOnExceptions = True, </para>
    /// <para>- Mode = TwoWay, </para> 
    /// <para>- UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus for 'Text' properties, otherwise PropertyChanged.</para>
    /// </summary>
#if !SILVERLIGHT
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Binding))]
#endif
    public sealed class ValidatedBinding : MarkupExtension
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTOR

        public ValidatedBinding(string path)
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            Path = path;

            /* possibly changed again in ProvideValue() */
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Default;
        }

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES

        public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }

        public object ConverterParameter { get; set; }

        public string ElementName { get; set; }

        public object FallbackValue { get; set; }

        public BindingMode Mode { get; set; }

#if !SILVERLIGHT
        [ConstructorArgument("path")]
#endif
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string StringFormat { get; set; }

        public UpdateSourceTrigger UpdateSourceTrigger { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region FIELDS

        bool _bound;
        DependencyProperty _property;
        FrameworkElement _element;

        #endregion

        #region OPERATIONS

        void ClearBinding()
        {
            _element.ClearValue(_property);
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IProvideValueTarget Target = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;

            if (Target == null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Cannot resolve the IProvideValueTarget. Are you binding to a property?");
            }

#if !SILVERLIGHT
            /* on text boxes, use a LostFocus update trigger */
            _property = Target.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;

            if (_property != null) {
                if (_property.Name.StartsWith("Text")) {
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
                }
                else {
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                }
            }
#endif

            _element = Target.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;

            if (_element != null) {

                _element.DataContextChanged += Element_DataContextChanged_SetBinding;

                if (_element.DataContext != null || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ElementName)) {

                    SetBinding();

                    /* can be replaced with normal reflection PropertyInfo.GetValue() */
                    return FastReflector.GetPropertyValue(/* object = */ _element.DataContext, /* property name = */ Path);
                }

                /* don't return null for value types */
                if (_property.PropertyType.IsValueType) {
                    return Activator.CreateInstance(_property.PropertyType);
                }

                return null;
            }

            return this;
        }

        void SetBinding()
        {
            _bound = true;

            Binding Binding = new Binding() {
                Path = new PropertyPath(this.Path),
                Converter = this.Converter,
                ConverterParameter = this.ConverterParameter,
                FallbackValue = this.FallbackValue,
                Mode = this.Mode,
                NotifyOnValidationError = true,
                StringFormat = this.StringFormat,
                ValidatesOnExceptions = true,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = this.UpdateSourceTrigger
            };

            /* only set when necessary to avoid a validation exception from the binding */
            if (_element.DataContext != null) { Binding.Source = _element.DataContext; }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ElementName)) { Binding.ElementName = ElementName; }

            _element.SetBinding(_property, Binding);
        }

        #endregion

        #region EVENT HANDLERS

        void Element_DataContextChanged_SetBinding(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* cleanup the old binding */
            if (_bound) { ClearBinding(); }

            SetBinding();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```